# How to identify the application sending this notifications?

Tags: linux, notifications

When I connect my smartphone to my Debian Linux machine, I see a popup notification from "Portable Media Player". "Who/what" is sending this notification? PMP is a common expression, so Google didn't help much.

[image: Screenshoot]

I'm using:

- Debian GNU/Linux 10
- KDE Frameworks 5.54.0
- Qt 5.11.3 (built against 5.11.3)

Comment: I don't know enough about it to warrant a full answer, but this behavior is generally controlled by **udev**, a daemon that monitor devices related events.

You could read more about it in the man to learn about the different rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting a notification *from* a portable media player, you are getting a notification *about* one: the system identifies your phone as a portable media player and is letting you know that a portable media player (your phone) has been connected. This is very common, phones are often recognized as media players or cameras instead of phones because the system detects the media files on them.

I don't use KDE, but that looks like a standard notification for a new connected device.
It is coming from some [kio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KIO) job sending, via dbus, the information to the [notification subsystem](https://community.kde.org/Plasma/Notifications). But since most part of the kio thing belongs to kde-frameworks and that you are running a **very** old version of them (5.96 current) it will be hard to tell you more.